# Silverlight Redirect

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hi guys can anyone tell me how to do this... I have a Silverlight application with two XAML pages. On the first one I have a button. When the button is clicked I would like to redirect the user to the second XAML page.

How can I accomplish this?

This is what i have so far:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.HelloMessage.Text = "Hello Universe";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
    }

    private void HelloMessage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is the load event for this page");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Application.Current.RootVisual = new MySecondPage();
```

where MySecondPage is the xaml page to which you want to navigate to.

Comment: this does not work.My second pages name is Page1.xaml
but this does not work i had Application.Current.RootVisual = new Page1();
but it just stays on the first page.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you really have a need to navigate from one XAML page to another, this will set you in the right direction: [Silverlight Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I would say, however, that in a Silverlight app, if you're simply trying to display different content on the page, you don't generally follow the standard web navigation paradigm.